# Complex constraints in the "where" clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to write a query that includes a complex constraint (at least it is to me). I need to pull rows of student data displaying their scores on three tests (Test A, Test B, and Test C from the TEST table) from my database. I need the following criteria met: I need the students to have a score of exactly 5 on Test A, additionally they need to have a score of at least 4 on both Test B and Test C with a score of 5 on Test B and Test C as well. How would I write the syntax for this? Thank you.

Comment: Help us help you! Please share the table[s] structure[s], some sample data and the result you'd like to get for that sample.

Comment: How can they "have a score of at least 4 on both Test B and Test C with a score of 5 on Test B and Test C as well"? You can't have a score of 4 AND 5 on the same test... right?

Comment: This is the most basic query.  What exactly seems to be a problem?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)

Comment: @JNevill - `5` matches `at least 4` criteria

Comment: I'm new to writing queries, I apologize if it is too simplistic. But I would greatly appreciate some feedback or an example on how to write the syntax for this. And to answer the first question, Student 1 could have a score of 4 on Test B and 5 on Test C and they would meet the criteria. These are two different tests. Student 2 could have a 4 on Test B and a score of 4 on Test C and they wouldn't meet the criteria. I hope that is clearer.

Comment: A=5 and b>=4 and C>=4

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to approach this.  Here's one.  (I'm making assumptions about field names and table structure for the sake of example):

```
;
WITH A
as  (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Test
    WHERE   TestID = 'A'
)
,   B
as  (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Test
    WHERE   TestID = 'B'
)
,   C
as  (
    SELECT *
    FROM   Test
    WHERE  TestID = 'C'
)
-- Pull it all together
SELECT  A.StudentID
    ,   ScoreA = A.Score
    ,   ScoreB = B.Score
    ,   ScoreC = C.Score
FROM    A
   INNER JOIN B
        ON  A.StudentID = B.StudentID
   INNER JOIN C
        ON  A.StudentID = C.StudentID
-- Filter
WHERE   A.Score = 5
   AND  B.Score >= 4
   AND  C.Score >= 4
   AND  (B.Score = 5 or C.Score = 5)
```

This is based on the assumption that the scores for A, B, and C are all in separate rows in the `Test` table, and that you want the result to have all three scores in the same row.

If they are all in the same row already, you can skip the CTEs, and just use the `WHERE` clause, with the fields and prefixes appropriately renamed.

Comment: Thank you for this, it is extremely helpful!

Comment: Glad to hear it!  If it was helpful, please consider marking it as your accepted answer.  Thanks.